# Set child form image from parent form?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am making some achievement pop ups for a lame game and so I made a custom messagebox form and I have been successful in setting the popups picturebox image with local images but I need help using embedded resources as images.

So far Ive used constructors to set the images and string but I can't use them for embedded images.

Parent Form:

```
MessageForm MsgFrm = new MessageForm
{
AchievementString = "L33t H4x0r - Reach 1337 score.",
PictureString = "C:\\Users\\Resources\\H4x0r_50x50.jpg"
};
MsgFrm.Show();
```

Child Form:

```
public string Achstring { get; set; }
public string Picstring { get; set; }
private void MessageForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
achievement_lbl.Text = AchievementString;
achievement_pic.Image = Image.FromFile(PictureString);
}
```

Using the code above I can only use local images and my goal is to use images embedded in resources but to pass them as an arg of sorts as above.

Comment: Sure, just give `MessageForm` a public property or constructor parameter of type `System.Drawing.Image`. Parent can load the image however it likes, from wherever, and hand it to `MessageForm`. `MessageForm` then assigns it to `achievement_pic.Image` in the Load handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either pass the `Image` object to a constructor or declare an `Image` property to set.

```
public MessageForm(Image img)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    achievement_pic.Image = img;
}
```

Or

*Parent form*

```
MessageForm MsgFrm = new MessageForm
{
    AchievementString = "L33t H4x0r - Reach 1337 score.",
    PictureImg = embeddedPicture
};
MsgFrm.Show();
```

*Child form*

```
public string Achstring { get; set; }
public Image PicImage { get; set; }

private void MessageForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    achievement_lbl.Text = AchievementString;
    achievement_pic.Image = PicImage
}
```

If you need more control in the parent form, you could make the control `public` or create a `public` property for the image.

```
public Control PicControl => achievement_pic;
```